# Proof that interval $]0,1[$ is an open set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have this question in my set of exercises of real analysis:

> prove that the interval $]0,1[$ is an open set.

The definition says

> the set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is open if for all $a \in A$, $\exists \delta \gt 0$ such that $B[a; \delta] \subset A$.

Although I get the intuition of this definition somehow, I don't really know how to prove the statement mathematically. In particular, I don't know how to choose my $\delta$.

Any tips are welcomed.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: Try to prove that the complement of $]0,1[$ is closed

Comment: The basi hint is: take a point and try to find a ball centered on it and contained in the set. I know it may sound basic, but I promise if you follow the hint you will be able to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a\in A$, take $\delta=\min\{a,1-a\}$ (that is, $\delta$ is the smallest between the distances from $a$ to $0$ and to $1$). Then $(a-\delta,a+\delta)\subset(0,1)$.

Comment: @MatthieuRousseau To formally proof that last inclusion: suppose $x \in (a-\delta, a+\delta)$. So $x > a-\delta$ and as $\delta \le a$, we know $a-\delta \ge 0$ and so $x > a-\delta  \ge 0$ hence $x >0$; also $\delta \le 1-a$ so $a+\delta \le 1$ and $x < a+\delta \le 1$ implies $x < 1$. Just to show we don't rely on a "picture".

Answer (score 0):

For $a \in (0,1)$ set $$\delta = \frac12(1-|2a-1|)$$

Then $B(a, \delta) = (a-\delta, a+\delta) \subseteq (0,1)$. Indeed,

$$a-\delta = a-\frac12(1-|2a-1|) = \left(a-\frac12\right) + \left|a-\frac12\right| \ge 0$$

$$a+\delta = a+\frac12(1-|2a-1|) = \left(a+\frac12\right) - \left|a-\frac12\right| \le \left(a+\frac12\right) - \left(a-\frac12\right) =1 $$